# System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.CGDisplayBounds error running simple mono app on MacOS

Tags: macos, mono, macports

When trying to run a simple Mono application on Mac OS X i run into the following issue:

```
Stacktrace:
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.CGDisplayBounds (intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.get_WorkingArea () <0x00035>
```

The source code for the sample app is:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class test {

        public static void Main() {
                Form fm1 = new Form();
                TextBox Tb1 = new TextBox();
                Tb1.Text="text";
                Tb1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10,10);
                Tb1.Size=new System.Drawing.Size(80,20);

                fm1.Controls.Add(Tb1);
                Application.Run(fm1);
        }
}
```

compiled with

> mcs test.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll -r:System.Drawing.dl

it compiles o.k. as test.exe. Trying to run it as

> mono test.exe

then leads to the stacktrace above.
The issue is mentioned in a forum-thread at:
http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Not-sure-if-this-is-a-bug-or-my-env-tt4656767.html

and i was able to replicate it exactly in the following environment:

- Mac OS 10.7.5
- Mac Ports 2.2.0
- Mono 2.10.9

The bug report at
http://trac.macports.org/ticket/1936

might be slightly related to the issue since gdiplus needs to be configured and
it is mentioned in this bug report that there might be an issue in the way Mono Cairo and Xquartz try to work together:
http://trac.macports.org/ticket/1936#comment:25

Now it would be great to know how  to get this working without having to wait for the bug report (9 years old ...) to be fixed.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX seems to say:
"Mono's implementation of the System.Windows.Forms API is built on top of Carbon and can only run with Mono on 32 bit systems. The look and feel of System.Windows.Forms applications mimics the Windows style and does not currently render like a native OSX application."

Comment: Installing the latest mono from
http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html
and running
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono test.exe
works (for comparison)